# How to find a common multple by creating and looping through 2 arrays at the same time, javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to create an 2 arrays of integers at the same time until one common value is find in the 2 arrays. I don't know when this common integer will be find, so I don't know where to stop my loop until the match is find.

Here is the example that I want to achieve when the 2 array are already created:

```
var arr1 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27];
var arr2 = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45];
var arr3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){

if (arr1.includes(arr2[i])){
  arr3.push(arr2[i]);
}
}
```

here, the common integer is 15. arr3 return 15.

I am trying to get to the same result without knowing with the common multiplier will be find but can't find the correct way to do it.

I would like to achieve this by doing something like this :

```
var num1 = [3, 5];

var res = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  if (num1[0]*i.includes(num1[1]*i)){
    res.push(i);
  }
}
```

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to find integers in common or integers that have factors in common?

Comment: what do you mean by multiplier? of what value?

Comment: Are you asking: how do I find the common value between the two arrays? In the given example, you are looking for the number 15?

Comment: You can do this by continually toggling arrays, each time adding additional elements until the latest one is equal to or larger than the largest element of the other array.  When they are equal you can quit.  But there are much better ways of getting the least common multiple, if that's all you're after.

Comment: @Displayname the number `15` is the only common number between both arrays.  The OP wants to do something different, however, what he has stated nobody understands.

Comment: @NinaScholz: If I'm correct, read "multiplier" as "multiple".  I *think* this is just a route to either least common multiple, or a list of factors up to the LCM.

Comment: Are you attempting to reduce fractions? Are you looking for the Least Common Multiple and Greatest Common Factor?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't express myself correctly! i am looking for the least common multiple between the 2 given numbers. My ideas was to multiple the two number with the for loop until one value match. My thought was to create 2 different array that stop when the LCM is find. and return only the LCM. Sorry for the confusion! first time I'm explaining an issue about coding!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for this as a way to find the least common multiple (LCM), then this is far overblown, but if you want the list of multiples of each up to the least common multiple, this might do it:

```js
const last = (arr) => arr[arr.length - 1]

const buildMultiples = (a, b) => {
  while (last(a) < last(b)) {
    a.push(last(a) + a[0])
  }
  if (last(a) == last(b)) {
    return [a, b]
  }
  return buildMultiples (b, a)
}

console.log(buildMultiples ([3], [5]))
```

But if you're just looking for the LCM, then you should try a purely numeric technique.

Note that I use recursive rather than iterative techniques here.  While there are many cases for which either makes sense, here it seems to me that any iterative technique would be *much* less understandable than this recursive one.  (I'd love to be proven wrong on this.)

(Also note that there is no error checking.  If you don't supply two arrays holding single positive integers, things could go very wrong.)

Comment: Hello Scott, Yes I am looking for the least common multiple. I thought that by breaking down the challenge like this I could achieve it, but I couldn't do what I had in mind:
- multiply the 2 numbers by i until a common value is find from the numbers generated.

What purely numeric technique are you talking about if I can ask?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When asking questions, make sure you at least mention your underlying problem.  Many people here could quickly steer you toward how to solve the LCM problem.  But more time was spent trying to understand what you meant with your two arrays.  You can probably search here for LCM answers or note the relationship between LCM and Greatest Common Divisor (GCD): `lcm(a, b) === a * b / gcd(a, b)`.  (And then figure out GCD, or search for that here!)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Learning Javascript is one of an experience! haha but a fun one!